# MySQL Multi Level Constraint

Tags: mysql, database-design

I've been having trouble enforcing my data model in MySQL and I was wondering if there are any better ways to do this.

Model:

```
Platforms <- Has many groups

Groups <- Has one platform, Has many SymbolSets

SymbolSets <- Belongs to many groups
```

My problem is that SymbolSets can only belong to groups that have the same platform. So if Platform A has Group A with SymbolSet A then Platform B with Group B shouldn't be able to get SymbolSet A, but any group in Platform A should be able to get it.

Right now I have a link table between SymbolSets and Groups and I enforce the uniqueness per platform in code, but I'd rather have a solution enforced in the DB so nobody can go muck around with it and break things. I would prefer to not have this many to many relationship in the first place, but that doesn't really fit our business model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Platform     
----------
PlatformId
PRIMARY KEY (PlatformId)

Grouping        
----------
GroupingId
PlatformId
PRIMARY KEY (GroupingId, PlatformId)
FOREIGN KEY (PlatformId)            
  REFERENCES Platfrom(PlatformId)

SymbolSet         
----------
SymbolSetId 
PRIMARY KEY (SymbolSetId)
```

When a `SymbolSet` is to be assigned to a `Group` (a new row in `SymbolSetToGroup`), it first has to be assigned to the same `Platform` that the `Group` belong to (so a new row in `SymbolSetAssigned` first).

```
SymbolSetAssigned               --- assigned to Platform
-----------------
SymbolSetId 
PlatformId
PRIMARY KEY (SymbolSetId)
UNIQUE KEY (SymbolSetId, PlatformId)
FOREIGN KEY (SymbolSetId)                              
  REFERENCES SymbolSet(SymbolSetId)
FOREIGN KEY (PlatformId)            
  REFERENCES Platfrom(PlatformId)

SymbolSetToGroup
----------------
SymbolSetId 
GroupingId
PlatformId
PRIMARY KEY (SymbolSetId, GroupingId)
FOREIGN KEY (SymbolSetId, PlatformId)                              
  REFERENCES SymbolSetAssigned(SymbolSetId, PlatformId)
FOREIGN KEY (GroupingId, PlatformId)             
  REFERENCES Grouping(GroupingId, PlatformId)
```

Comment: +1 but the target of a foreign key reference must be either the whole PRIMARY KEY or a whole UNIQUE KEY.  So you need to define keys differently in the SymbolSetAssigned and Grouping tables.

Comment: Actually, that's not true in InnoDB; it's non-standard, but an FK can reference any non-unique set of indexed columns.  But trust me, don't go there if you value your sanity.

Comment: @BillKarwin: Yes, thank you. Is that a limitation of MySQL or of other products? I would guess that an FK reference to a superset of the PK (of a Unique Key) would be valid.

Comment: SQL-99: "The Columns in the foreign key must match the number of, and have a comparable <data type> with, the corresponding Columns in the referenced unique key." http://kb.askmonty.org/en/constraint_type-foreign-key-constraint

Comment: MySQL 5.6: "...the system does not enforce a requirement that the referenced columns be UNIQUE or be declared NOT NULL. The handling of foreign key references to nonunique keys or keys that contain NULL values is not well defined for operations such as UPDATE or DELETE CASCADE. You are advised to use foreign keys that reference only UNIQUE and NOT NULL keys." I don't think I need to comment further on *that*.

Comment: I don't think the issue is about NULLs here. It's whether one is allowed to reference `(a,b)` where `a` is PRIMARY or UNIQUE (and `b` not null) and no unique key exists on `(a,b)`.